# su - postgres No directory, logging in with HOME=/

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I'm using these instructions for installing PostgresQL: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/linux-postgresql-install-and-configure-from-source/

(Perhaps that's my first mistake but I've used various documentation trying to get this installed with no luck and this one made the most sense)

Everything seems to go smoothly until I get to Step 6: Initialize postgreSQL data directory. I enter

su - postgres

in the command line and get this back

No directory, logging in with HOME=/

And I can't do anything else from there. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you do Step 4: Create postgreSQL user account? Does the postgreSQL home directory exist and have the correct permissions?

Comment: Yes. It did say that the user already existed so I changed the password and that worked just fine.

Comment: I suspect that something about the postgreSQL home directory is incorrect. Without information we're just guessing.

Comment: Is there any additional information I can provide? Where I can I look?

Comment: The information we need is the existence of the postgreSQL home directory and the permissions on this directory.

Comment: This often happening on official docker/postgres images.
Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Try to find if is postgres user created and where is his home directory.
For example :

```
# cat /etc/passwd
postgres:x:999:999::/home/postgres:/bin/sh
```

You can see that postgres user uses /home/postgres

If that directory doesn't exist create it and set proper owner : postgres and read/write access.

Comment: This didn't solve the problem for me… I wasn't having any issues until I rebooted/upgraded, so it seems to be an OS issue on my end.